# TypeScript optional object key not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object with conditional keys. I.e.:

```
const headers: RequestHeaders = {};

if (...) {
  headers.foo = 'foo';
}

if (...) {
  headers.bar = 'bar';
}
```

I'm new to TS and I expected this to work:

```
type RequestHeaders = {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string,
};
```

However, I'm passing this to `fetch` and the type definition for `fetch`'s headers is `{ [key: string]: string }`. I'm getting:

```
Type 'RequestHeaders' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Property 'foo' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

The only way I could get this to work is `type RequestHeaders = { [key: string]: string };`. Is there a way to limit the keys to a set of predefined strings?

Comment: Does declaring `headers` as `Partial<RequestHeaders>` help?

Comment: @Phix `Partial` will not help because the `fetch` type for `headers` says that none of the values can be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch API does not accept a headers object that has a key with an undefined value. Since each of your optional types can be either `string | undefined`, the compiler is rejecting them.

Here is an approach that filters the headers to remove those with undefined values. Its [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) (`is`) keeps the compiler happy.

```
const buildHeaders = (requestHeaders: RequestHeaders): HeadersInit =>
  Object.entries(requestHeaders).filter(
    (entry): entry is [string, string] => entry[1] !== undefined
  );

const headers: RequestHeaders = {};

type RequestHeaders = {
  foo?: string; // optional
  bar?: string; // optional
  baz: string; // required!
};

fetch("Some Data", {
  headers: buildHeaders(headers)
});
```

The advantage of this approach is that it lets you limit the keys to a set of predefined strings while also letting you to specify whether each is required or optional.

Answer (score 1):

The header data of `fetch` method must be type like

```
type HeadersInit = Headers | string[][] | Record<string, string>;
```

For your case, I think you will define `headers` type as a alias of `Record<string, string>`. For keys configuration (`foo`, `bar`), I will have a suggestion: Fixed header keys. Then, you will define all header keys to a type like:

```
type HeaderKeys = 'foo' | 'bar';

type RequestHeaders = Record<HeaderKeys, string>; // the same: type RequestHeaders = Record<'foo' | 'bar', string>;

const headers: RequestHeaders = {} as RequestHeaders; // force cast
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I can say, If you want to move from well-defined optional attributes to flexible but required key-value attributes, you need to cast by hand. That could be made using strategies:

### Making a For Loop Accepting Any Value

```
type RequestHeaders = {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string,
};

type FetchResult = {
  [key: string]: string;
}

let headers: RequestHeaders = {};
const i = 2
if (i > 1) {
  headers.foo = 'foo-value';
}
if (i > 0) {
  headers.bar = 'bar-value';
}

const fetchResult: FetchResult = {};
for (let key in headers) {
  let value = headers[key] // <==== This will be of the type Any
  if (value) {
    fetchResult[key] = "" + value;
  }
}
console.log(fetchResult);
```

### Making Explicit Attributes Set

```js
type RequestHeaders = {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string,
};

type FetchResult = {
  [key: string]: string;
}

let headers: RequestHeaders = {};
const i = 2
if (i > 1) {
  headers.foo = 'foo-value';
}
if (i > 0) {
  headers.bar = 'bar-value';
}

const fetchResult: FetchResult = {};
if (headers.foo) {
  fetchResult['foo'] = headers.foo;
}
if (headers.bar) {
  fetchResult['bar'] = headers.bar;
}
console.log(fetchResult);
```

### Using the Nullable Cast

Similar to the [@ShaunLutin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384860/typescript-optional-object-key-not-behaving-as-expected/60385205#60385205) example, using the " as " command allows you to check the result of the cast.

```
type RequestHeaders = {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string,
};

type FetchResult = {
  [key: string]: string;
}

let headers: RequestHeaders = {};
const i = 2
if (i > 1) {
  headers.foo = 'foo-value';
}
if (i > 0) {
  headers.bar = 'bar-value';
}

let fetchResultNullable: FetchResult | undefined;
fetchResultNullable = headers as FetchResult;

console.log(fetchResultNullable);
```

[You can see those examples in this Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=27#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYAJCBDAJhATilALxQDeAUFFAGYD2dA-AFxRr4CWAdgOYA0VKACMs+Fm2CdeAgL4BuChVCQoAMQjAAxgAs4KRABtgJcoIDaAawghW7bjwC6tyfYUzFBjVG3Y8hVnBIqBi+BESkZPIUmnRcaFAcJgBMFBw0UAAUiQB8UACMAJSm1D64YQB09HQmAORVALQAblgGyDVuqelZULkADEWUJaGE5SL4tWNNLW0dFJ7GNBo6eobArOpauqirJpEKaZmlfiiVDAOCi5srRmZ1DDUOJkcVVR0HGc8jY+fUl8vbNxqYweT2GJzGs3mtCWW30RiS6xh12MESi9HGGShVhACS43jBPygUOarWgpE+KEs1gccigAHo6VAADzEUgAFW0HCIAHcOAYDN4sI1oCTkFAAIJcECCd6iiCE35IgHAJJUkCPUgAIk1UAA1FA5QpqO53DE4nRPOUDHQeBk-rDVgUFGaUBaIFabXalXCVU6gA)

Comment: I don't think your type would work for an object that had both properties

Comment: @Bergi is right, this is the way to do it:
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-evt-demo-matcher-return-boolean-zy13as?embed=1&file=index.ts
```typescript
declare const cond1: boolean;
declare const cond2: boolean;


const headers = {
    ...(cond1 ? { "foo": "yes" } : {}),
    ...(cond2 ? { "bar": "yes" } : {})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler is protecting you.
`RequestHeaders` is not a valid `Record<string,string>` it is right.
It's a good thing that it does not let you pass `RequestHeaders` to `fetch()`
as depending on the implementation of fetch() some `RequestHeaders` could make it throw.

```js
/** 
 * The question mark means that the key
 * can be missing 
 * OR
 * The key is present and the value is a string
 * OR
 * The key is present and the value is undefined
 */
type RequestHeaders = {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string,
};


/*
{ [k in 'foo' | 'bar']: string };
<=>
{ foo: string; bar: string; };

It's not a workaround, it's not the same type as RequestHeaders
and the example you gave doesn't transpile if you use it in place
of RequestHeaders.
*/


/**
 * This is an implementation of fetch that throw
 * if you pass it an object that have properties 
 * with undefined value
 */
function fetch(requestHeaders: { [key: string]: string; }): string{
  return Object.keys(requestHeaders)
    .map(key => `${key} => ${requestHeaders[key].toUpperCase()}`)
    .join(" --- ")
    ;
}

/**
 * This is an implementation of the function that transform a 
 * record with values that can be undefined to
 * a record where if there is a key the value
 * is a string. 
 */
const toStringRecord= (
  partialStringRecord: { [key: string]: string | undefined; }
): { [key: string]: string; }=> {

    const out: { [key: string]: string; } = {};

    Object.keys(partialStringRecord)
        .filter(key=> typeof partialStringRecord[key] === "string")
        .forEach(key=> out[key] = partialStringRecord[key]!)
    ;

    return out;

}

const headers: RequestHeaders = {};


const cond1= true;
const cond2= false;

{

    const requestHeaders: RequestHeaders= {};

    //In your example you dont assign if cond is false 
    //but you could verry well wrote things this way and
    //it would be perfectly valid typewise.
    requestHeaders.foo = cond1 ? "foo" : undefined;

    requestHeaders.bar = cond2 ? "bar" : undefined;

    try{

      //It's good that the compiler does not let you pass this to fetch
      //as this throw.
      fetch(requestHeaders as any);

    }catch(error){

      console.log(error.message);

    }

    //Works as expected, str === "foo => FOO"
    const str= fetch(
      toStringRecord(requestHeaders)
    );

    console.log(str);

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQKhAIChwgVALApuAjgV0QZwC4EsD2AduALYCGATgNamJnHbxnbiPJWICe0EAxveABGyErkyZchAOZQY4APIAlHqyTgOncGPAAHClkSEW9ACarkANzIAbDFszgy4HBUlSVSlW3Vd7u-ZiGxoRm3la2yNpoIYgAZpKIJjzAkNicOsiKiOhY2AASdCaIFA4AvOAA3tDgsfj4APwAXM7YrtIANNWClE0tbVKdAL4A3JBjoKnpmdkYOAVkRSXg5RXgANo0kuAA5LX42+AAPjvdFNsAus0ubuAjkAA8pQB8kxngWTlzhcVllTV1V1abmGQkogP6ILukAAkthtg5CPhjOAAO74aiUfDREztLRwhFI8zOMgkZBpN6mcyQRAADxJOmsyE4WPAUjIFmQJnwWEI2xYaOoWli4GZaHAaECeIAdJAQClxmAVAhtNoBLgSAzEKSjMwCMR8MLYohsLx4KpmKoKPgUSpcMLRboyOI8Y59YIAFaIXgsRgWpgc-z4DIUPBYWQQFG4RjimLxQiJcDhDDJSCxaLevU1Y2mgAU+k++W+JWaqw2XHBbkufWBtwAlBXpFVwOB9Ng0BRiPIPV7sFKNJg8zNcvNFpha9Vm1LyDocxplk9wAADAAkFQ0g3n4FX+dmhYWPzLnHOUuw+AAqjpgwBhJ2IHO1waL8fNyfu-CSHMAInAAFo-+BP2fF9RkGBUQCVeAVQcbwpEMYobBqdM8CIVh8FYCh6EwA10RIRxwxbL18DMSNoyTMNfRYfhiGEGMijjBNTxUJx9F4dFiKQfQhXMTjVR8TQwhsZM5F465pClcMUlYwgcFQgBlIFpCyViKBMcoc2qHRKDwGx5P6JS2JLdYNAbKQq1EmRjmxOIEhMSFIHrP5DxMsyFKkSFnkqMYX3AKSZKxbBDKc6tpBciFbmWSooW8rtPW9PsuAHTSQ1wHTXP0lSgO8yd4msbBilnLgPPJRADUdZLUr0wiVMPc5llKcpP3MwCJyyqVagoABRMhcw0Dz-JqiKku06xdLcdKTBqgBCTLwFGFrW3bfU0GwObQMgXyWCQfdi3eIcvm234KihdaiBkqSTAARnKVoMFGDafKIEwACZyliGxAjmqoWvundhyLTBmg+XcRx+FYopfYBgGhYhRQocBaXpRkRRZLkjEccRcCkYg7QekI-De6xJRayHBGW5GxVYtBrDMDkKAoTQUUQaxrFRK08tUNxoMghwUTITRTGJ4Ao1RLFqaEZBgyNb1rE0cJcFCKZI0CGVvN+-bRzauoIvOi7wHqAC9m-ZorPo2yvJfNW9w105tcep69YA04jdo6z4zNlrWk4L6svASHYXhVk6lCJgfTUViNVwRkzC5MNERYRkWAdTTnUYbRTyzE14Ba5tIadDmuatFEVayo1M8HAsQaWPP6E4WtRh9n2WsGfgy+KK0KFrb2st8-BGSlax8CkHM2-RKcsEwMhYLr83mzW7zIeVBxtAFGg89pDJvUSb7TpYFxXuzeB1J909RsUqqTHL4H-pm6ft+k3vEH7wecxcW-BiAA)

[**Slackblitz link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-evt-demo-matcher-return-boolean-dj7xzt?embed=1&file=index.ts).

NOTE: That Slackblitz is configured with typescript very permissive, you don't get all the warnings you get in the TS playgound.

Comment: So this is caused by TS not making a distinction between a key not existing and a key whose value is `undefined`? I guess something similar to your filter solution is to cast to `{ [key: string]: string }`

Comment: Yes, you are right the code that you provided gives an error because typescript does not make the difference you mentioned but it's a feature, not a bug.

I highly advise against casting, it is not safe, if you want to do it you have to be 100% sure that you never assigned undefined to a key.

However, I recommend, when possible, to directly instantiate the RequestHeaders and avoiding to change it later on. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-evt-demo-matcher-return-boolean-zy13as?embed=1&file=index.ts

Answer (score -1):

```sh
$ npm i -D @types/node @types/express
```

just extend from express

```
export interface MyPrequest extends express.Resquest {}
```

Comment: How is that going to help with using `fetch`? And how does the type definition of `express.Resquest` look like?

Comment: The context if not relevant it's not a question about fetch or express is a question about typescript.